# Redirect output of a startup script to terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, startup, log, output

I have a shell script init.sh that invokes a javascript script app.js like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
node app.js
```

In the js script there are some console.log that i would like to see on the terminal. If I directly run the .sh script, `./init.sh` I see the logs, but when the script is called by a service at boot I can't see any log.

How do i redirect output of a startup script on the terminal?

Comment: have you tried creating a systemd service? you can verbose output of systemd services with `systemctl my-script.service status -o verbose`

Comment: Do you want to run a terminal with the output on startup? That’s as easy as e.g.: `xterm -e node app.js`

Comment: My device is headless, i'm connected via serial or SFTP, so i got this error xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s
xterm: DISPLAY is not set